# I try to foreach loop XML file that is loaded from XML to json

Tags: php, json, xml, foreach

I try to foreach loop XML file. First it is turned to JSON from XML file and then to PHP array that I am trying to loop with foreach function (With Zend Framework).

Problem is when XML file haves only one activity then whole code not work and when XML file haves a more than one activity then code works:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    'library',
    get_include_path()
)));

require_once('Zend/Loader.php');

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Loader_Autoloader');

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents("activities.xml");

$jsonContents = Zend_Json::fromXml($xmlStringContents, true);

$decodedValues = Zend_Json::decode($jsonContents);

$project[0] = array("key" => "", "value" => "Please select...");

$i = 1;

foreach ($decodedValues['Envelope'] as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $keyEnvelope => $valueEnvelope) {

    if (is_array($valueEnvelope)) {
        foreach ($valueEnvelope['EFIAIFProjActivity'] as $keyEFIAIFProjTable => $valueEFIAIFProjTable) {
            if (is_array($valueEFIAIFProjTable)) {
                foreach ($valueEFIAIFProjTable as $projectValue) {

                    if (isset($_GET['project'])) {

                        if ($_GET['project']==$projectValue['Project']['ProjId'] && $_GET['project'] != "") {
                            $project[$i] = array("key" => $projectValue['smmActivities']['ActivityNumber'], "value" => $projectValue['smmActivities']['PSADescription']);
                            $i++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

if ($i==1) {
    $project[$i] = array("key" => "NO_ACTIVITY_000001", "value" => "No Activity");
}

$projects = array("values" => $project);

if (isset($_GET['callback'])) {
echo $_GET['callback']."(";
echo Zend_Json::encode($projects);
echo ")";
}
```

I need to get this code work like that way it makes a JSON string with "Please select..." and "No Activity" to Activity dynamic drop down menu if dynamic drop down menu *Project* selected project haves no activities in Atlassian JIRA and Tempo Add-on. And if selected project haves one or more activities in XML file then Activity drop down menu haves these activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to not convert the XML to JSON. `SimpleXML` allows you to use object/traversable syntax on the XML DOM. So if you access a child element as object property is is treated as a single value, if you access as as a list (with foreach) it is treated as a list.

The main difference to you current solution is that you have to use object property syntax, not array syntax.

Another thing is that you code looks like it reads SOAP. While SOAP uses a XML syntax for serialization, it is NOT "just XML". You're better of using a specific SOAP library.

Comment: Now I got it almost to work but SimpleXML and its foreach loop makes this JSON string: ({"values":[{"key":"","value":"Please select..."},{"key":{"0":"000003_006"},"value":{"0":"Some Activty"}}]}) not ({"values":[{"key":"","value":"Please select..."},{"key":"000003_006","value":"Some Activty"}]})

Comment: I think that SimpleXML is a correct way to do this but I need some help more.

Answer (score 0):

If XML has single node then `Zend Framework` converts it to JSON as key value pair.

If XML has more than one node then `Zend Framework` converts it to a JSON array.

You can handle this in 2 ways.

1. Check if its an array then loop it else access the values directly by its key
2. If the node is not an array, convert it to an array after its decoded.